# Maximum upload size on iOS / NSURLRequest / NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm uploading multi-gigabyte files from iPhones/iPods, and I noticed that NSURLConnection and friends incorrectly use signed 32-bit integers for the number of bytes in the upload

(all of Apple's other API's use (long long) a.k.a. (int64_t) - allowing you to deal with any file that could exist)

When I try to upload files over 3GB, streamed from a file, I get overflows in the data coming back from Apple - but this could be a problem with anything in the chain (web proxy, cache, server). I'm still debugging this, but in the meantime....

Apple docs don't mention a size limit on uploads - is there one?

Bizarrely, I get no problems for uploads up to 3GB (even though the overflow ought to be at 2GB) - it's going over 3GB that always overflows. (I've triple-checked all my source that I'm not using 32bit types anywhere, so I'm fairly confident it's a problem somewhere between iOS and the server(s))